# Remove a :after pseudo element on hover the same element

Tags: css, overlay, pseudo-element

I have the div .folio-cube
that contains the following 2 divs:
.front and .bottom

By default the .front contains a colour image and .bottom a text description.

On hover, the colour image is overlaid by the description.

My customisation:

I have placed a colour overlay to the .front using a ::after pseudo element

*(not possible using a ::before)*

something like that

```
.front::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #dd7d33, #cf6324);
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

What i can't do:

On hovering the .folio-cube, i need to completely hide the pseudo element overlay, or even the entire .front div, so as the .bottom div appears.

I have tried various solutions, without success...

The website i am trying to do this is [here](https://vasilisrizos.gr/test/)

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.front:not(:hover)::after`

Comment: `.front:not(:hover)::after` is the best solution, as the user above said. If not possible or practical, try doing something like `.front:hover::after { content: unset; }`, as having an empty `content` field will make the `::after` disappear